# Face changer camera live faces add

Tags: android, kotlin, face-detection, face-recognition

Currently, we are developing one app which bases on face detection. when face detected on live camera we place another image left side of the detected area so it will look like a selfie picture.

so currently while taking a screenshot of camera view and drawn face area on canvas is showing black so we know capture screenshot of camera surface is not possible.

Does anyone have an idea to develop this type of application?

/**
     * Draws the face annotations for position on the supplied canvas.
     */
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Face face = mFace;
        if (face == null) {
            return;
        }

```
    // Draws a circle at the position of the detected face, with the face's track id below.
    float x = translateX(face.getPosition().x + face.getWidth() / 2);
    float y = translateY(face.getPosition().y + face.getHeight() / 2);

    // Draws a bounding box around the face.
    float xOffset = scaleX(face.getWidth() / 2.3f);
    float yOffset = scaleY(face.getHeight() / 2.3f);
    float left = x - xOffset;
    float top = y - yOffset;
    float right = x + xOffset;
    float bottom = y + yOffset;
    canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, mBoxPaint);

    // Bitmap to draw on the canvas
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            resources,
            R.drawable.ic_luncher);

    sclledBitmp=getResizedBitmap(bitmap, (int)face.getWidth()-70, (int) face.getHeight()-70);

    //Finally, Draw the source bitmap on the canvas
    canvas.drawBitmap(
            sclledBitmp, // Bitmap
            right, // Left
            top, // Top
            null // Paint
    );

    canvas.drawText("Width: " + (int)face.getWidth() + " \nright:"+right, right, top, mIdPaint);

}
```